# Error while creating SharePoint Custom Page Layout 2016

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016, custom-pages

In SharePoint on premises(2016).I have created a custom page layout which got deployed successfully and feature got activated. After that in site while creating the layout with the help of that layout I an getting "Sorry Something Went wrong Error message"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the steps from the article below:

**[How To Create A Page Layout (PageLayout) With ContentType](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Create-a-Page-Layout-(PageLayout)-with-ContentType-in-SharePoint-2013)**

And get more error message from ULS log, for SharePoint 2016, by default, ULS log locates in 
"**C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS**"